# Why doesn't curl download from file a onion service?

Tags: onion-services

I am attempting to download a file from a hidden service using curl. I downloaded the Tor client and launched it and from another terminal executed this:

```
curl --socks5 socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 https://check.torproject.org > /tmp/output.txt
```

After listing the contents of tmp I catted the file along with grepping for 'browser'. I found congratulations this browser is configured to use Tor. However when I attempt to connect to a hidden service it fails to resolve the hostname which i checked within Tor browser and it loads. I tried using `--socks5-hostname localhost:9050` and it downloaded the page just fine from the hidden service. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

According to `man curl`:

```
--socks5 <host[:port]>
       Use the specified SOCKS5 proxy  -  but  resolve  the  host  name
       locally.
```

This means `--socks5` will use local resolver which CANNOT resolve `.onion` names UNLESS you configured it to do so and configured `tor` relay to do IP address allocation for hidden services.

`--socks5-hostname` has this information in the man page:

```
--socks5-hostname <host[:port]>
       Use  the  specified  SOCKS5 proxy (and let the proxy resolve the
       host name).
```

This lets `tor` and its socks proxy do the resolution and handle the `.onion` name hence the connection succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Install torsocks. This is a wrapper that will allow command line tools like curl to use the Tor service in Linux.

Example:

torsocks curl yz7lpwfhhzcdyc5y.onion

Comment: But, torsocks will install/run a tor executable as well. Check that you don't have conflicts. I spent a day learning this.